# Writing scripts

Tags: windows, bash

I am new to scripts and have some questions . This is the path

```
c:/data/flow/gen/value/foo.txt
c:/data/flow/gen/secondvalue/cat.txt
c:/data/flow/gen/thirdvalue/bar.txt
```

I have to write a script to get all the .txt file inside the folder gen.

I am writing something like this .

```
find - path c:/*/gen/* -name "*.txt" | cat >> output.txt
```

But i am not getting the filenames in output file. Can someone help me with this. 
I just know the "gen" folder name and its path is hidden for me.  So i have to write a script accordingly

Comment: Really? Because you *should* be getting an error message...

Comment: I just wonder… how can you have something like `c:/` and the 'linux' tag at the same time?

Comment: Yea i am getting a file with nothing inside. No errors .

Comment: Yea sorry my bad..should not have tagged linux..really sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find directory -name "*.txt" -print -exec cat '{}' \; > output.txt

-print              # prints the filename
-exec cat '{}'      # cats the file
> output.txt        # puts it all into output.txt
```

You have to replace directory with the directory you want to search. 
This will work in a Linux shell but not in Windows.

If you are using Windows try using the "Find files and folders" feature.

Comment: Did this but still it shows an empty file. Nd one more thing i dont know gen's exact location also..So it should be something like c:/*/gen/*/

Answer (score 0):

Add one or more directories before your -path.

Delete the space between - and path, so it reads "-path".

Add a -print for portability, after the "*.txt" (separated by a space).

This is a "useless use of cat" - your find command can do the append - it's simpler and a little faster.

Is this cygwin?

You *might* need to \ escape your c:\ - colon is definitely a shell builtin, but I'm not sure if that'll matter in this case.